# Docker buildx on Travis CI

Tags: docker, travis-ci, docker-buildkit, ppc64le

I'm trying to build image for platform ppc64le via Docker Buildx and Buildkit on our enterprise Travis CI instance.

.travis.yml:

```
os: linux
dist: bionic
language: shell
branches:
  only:
    - master
before_install:
  - set -e
  # Configure environment so changes are picked up when the Docker daemon is restarted after upgrading
  - echo '{"experimental":true}' | sudo tee /etc/docker/daemon.json
  - export DOCKER_CLI_EXPERIMENTAL=enabled
  - sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
  - curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
  - sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) edge"
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confnew" install docker-ce
  - mkdir -vp ~/.docker/cli-plugins/
  - curl --silent -L "https://github.com/docker/buildx/releases/download/v0.3.0/buildx-v0.3.0.linux-amd64" > ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  - chmod a+x ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
jobs:
  include:
    - stage: build and push docker image
      script:
        - echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_USERNAME" --password-stdin  
        - sudo docker buildx build --platform linux/ppc64le --tag myimage:ppc64le -f src/main/docker/Dockerfile.ppc64 --push .
```

Build will fail on error:

```
$ sudo docker buildx build --platform linux/ppc64le --tag myimage:ppc64le -f src/main/docker/Dockerfile.ppc64 --push .
unknown flag: --platform
See 'docker --help'.
Usage:  docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND
```

Looks like Buildx extension is not enabled, but Docker info will show that experimental_cli is enabled.

Any ideas about how to enable buildx on Travis?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble myself but TravisCI official documentation states you need to install buildx plugin. Here: https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-build-what-about-travis/

From what I can see you are missing this in ***before_install***

```
  - mkdir -vp ~/.docker/cli-plugins/
  - curl --silent -L "https://github.com/docker/buildx/releases/download/v0.3.0/buildx-v0.3.0.linux-amd64" > ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  - chmod a+x ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
```

Comment: I tried to add docker-buildx binary like in your solution, but no luck, I get same error. Updated question with your answer too.